# How to point maven-verifier at right version of Maven?

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I am using [Maven Wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) on Travis because it ships with a super-old version of Maven by default.

The library being built runs integration tests using [maven-verifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html#maven-verifier). The latter forks a JVM to run each integration test using the (outdated) Maven instance installed on the system.

Is there a way to get maven-verifier to use the Maven version provided by Maven Wrapper?

Comment: Can you give more details cause it sounds a little bit weird to me using maven-verifier for integration tests ?

Comment: @khmarbaise What's weird about it? The title of [this section](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html#maven-verifier) seems to imply this is precisely what maven-verifier is designed for. See https://github.com/cmake-maven-project/cmake-maven-project/blob/master/cmake-maven-plugin/src/test/java/com/googlecode/cmakemavenproject/CompileMojoIntegrationTest.java for a concrete example of how we use it.

Comment: Ah...you are doing a maven plugin. Than it is not weird of course...For such purposes I would suggest to use the maven-invoker-plugin...furthermore I would suggest to use maven-failsafe-plugin for integration tests instead of maven-surefire-plugin....Apart from that you can set the maven version used by running via `maven.home` environment  variable. But that might be point for improving the docs...(May be you can create an JIRA issue for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the implementation of `org.apache.maven.it.Verifier#getMavenLauncher` (at version 1.7.2 when checked), it will attempt to use a Maven wrapper if that wrapper is present in the repository that you are running the test **on** (not in the project repository that is *running* the test).

```
boolean useWrapper = Files.exists(Paths.get(getBasedir(), "mvnw"));
```

`getBasedir()` is the root of the project folder being tested here. I had the same issue and I copied the `mvnw` and `.mvn` folders into the project I was testing, and it did indeed find the appropriate version of Maven.

My new *projects to be tested* look like this

```
default-test-project
    |_ .mvn/
    |_ mvnw
    |_ pom.xml
```

It's worth mentioning that `Verifier#getMavenLauncher` doesn't appear to check for a `mvnw.cmd` so this may not work on a Windows machine.